# AngularJs keep lists in pristine state

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

We have a mover directive with 2 lists controls and 4 buttons. I want to be able to add keepPristine property to this directive and if I set it to true, the control should not react on changes and set ng-dirty flag. I tried adding to the ng-change event of the list:

```js
 $scope.onChanged = function (assigned) {
                    $scope.selectedItem = assigned[0];
                    if ($scope.keepPristine)
                    {
                        $scope.form.assignedList.$pristine = true;
                        $scope.form.unAssignedList.$pristine = true;
                    }
                }
```

Unfortunately, when I inspect this control using Developer's Tools I see it's still has ng-dirty state. What should I do to make sure both lists are always in the pristine state regardless on my interaction with them?

Comment: I remember using a `$setPristine` function instead of `$pristine`, could you try it ?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use the method `$setPristine()` instead... and, if after that, it's not "pristine" yet then add an `$scope.$apply()` after the `$setPristine()` call.

Comment: I actually used a different solution at the end. I added no-dirty-check directive to both select lists and added setting form's dirty into buttons code (Move Left, Move Left All, etc.). Works fine.